# Separate Chrome webapp shortcuts from Chrome in Gnome Shell

Tags: fedora, gnome, chrome

I created some webapps in Google Chrome that will open in their own windows, like Google Keep, for example. But whenever I open them, it will say Google Chrome in the black bar (Gnome Shell) and in overview, it will be listed as a Google Chrome window rather than its own. Meaning I have to move around and actually find the window rather than simply clicking on it in the dash. It's not a big deal, but it works easier for my workflow. Windows and Ubuntu treat Chrome's webapps as their own applications, how can I get Gnome to do it, too?

[image: See, I have Google Keep opened, but it says Chrome.]

Comment: I don't know the answer, but "applications" and related things (like app name, app icon, etc) are mapped/associated with executables and process names via .desktop files. you may want to poke around `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: @strugee I've already some messing around in ~/.local/share/applications. That's where Chrome saves the webapps. I couldn't seem to make any meaningful changes.

Comment: So you found the ones that Unity creates?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not running Unity so I don't know where it would save it, if it even does.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the Fedora tag. You mentioned Ubuntu so I assumed you ran Unity at some point... silly me.